# how to convert NSDictionaryResults to NSManagedObject,

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject

I have the following code which pulls up cars from the database using the carparts.
However I was running into duplicates so I enabled the NSDictionaryResultsType with unique results (I think it is the only way to get rid of duplicates).

Now I believe I have an array of dictionaries NOT Car objects.
How do I get the car objects based on my results?

```
-(NSArray*) loadCarsFromCoreDataUsingCarParts:(NSMutableArray*)inputCarParts{
    NSLog(@"carParts =%@",inputCarParts);
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    //To find the cars we are using the carParts
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Car" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    //sets up fetch request details
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[self parseSearchObjectsIntoAPredicate:inputCarParts:3]];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    //Perform fetch
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *records = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return records;//i think this is an array of dictionaries
}
```

Comment: Your code specifically requests dictionary results. You don't have to do that if you don't want to.

Comment: but how do i remove the duplicates then? I have read [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES]; only works if you have NSDictionaryResultType

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem you're trying to solve here. If you have duplicate entries, your code above filters them out. So which managed objects do you want? Just one of the entries with duplicate data? Which one?

Comment: right now it is finding all carParts that a car object has. I get 56 results if I don't use nsdictionaryresults, I get 7 if I do (no duplicates, and seven cars have those parts, so this should be the result). However I need an array of cars (not of dictionaries referring to car parts). So how do I take this array an convert it to an array of car managedobjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also fetch `objectID` and retrieve the objects with a predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectID IN %@", objectIDs]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSManagedObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:]

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html